# How to install Webbsy plugin in Photoshop CS6

Tags: photoshop

This may be a very easy question, but I can't find it's solution.

I am using Adobe Photoshop CS6. I am trying to install [Webbsy](http://www.webbsy.com/).
It is a 3rd party Adobe Photoshop Plugin. I have downloaded it and get a **.zxp** file (webbsy-cc-1.2.3.zxp). I have downloaded it for CS6 (Adobe CC is also available).

But I don't know how to install a 3rd party plugin in Adobe Photoshop CS6.
So, I can't use it. I am using win 8.1 OS and I want to use 14 day trial or this plugin.

Can anyone help me please to install it?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On http://www.webbsy.com/download

It say:
Please Note
You must have Adobe Extension Manager installed in order to use this plugin.

Comment: No, it is not I am asking for

Comment: You want to install Webbsy to your Adobe Photoshop CS6  ? Or, what is the third party you want to install ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Adobe Extension Manager](https://www.adobe.com/fr/products/extension-manager.html) to install plugins

Answer (score 0):

First Open Below link.
--> http://www.webbsy.com/

Then click on **Download for Adobe CC** or **Download for Adobe CS6**

Comment: NOTE :  You must have Adobe Extension Manager installed in order to use this plugin.